# is it possible to deploy a Local iso file to a hard drive on a remote machine

Tags: iso-image, redhat-enterprise-linux, remote-access

so I've got an iso that I created and it is roughly 197gb. I compressed the file into an iso.gz and saved it to my local machine. I now would like to try to deploying this iso to a remote box. now for the more detailed portions:

I am using a live RHEL 7.5 USB that is plugged into the remote box, and I issue the following command to view the disks currently mounted on the system:

```
Fdisk -l
```

which returns to me that the desired drive (my 1tb *destination* drive) is 
/dev/sda

I have tried the following command with no luck, and i'm not sure if this is the correct sequence or if it is even possible to zcat remotely:

```
zcat myisoname.iso.gz | ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx | /dev/sda
```

when issuing the above zcat command the console freezes for a moment and then starts printing out random letters and symbols. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the second pipe is happening on your local machine. You should quote the remote command. Something like `zcat myisoname.iso.gz | ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'dd of=/dev/sda'` should work.

Comment: I see, and usually with zcat when doing it locally you need to use redirection ">" would I need to use this instead of the  'dd of=/dev/sda'? or in this case I suppose the dd command just directs the output?

Comment: I think that `ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'cat - >/dev/sda'` will work too.

Comment: Thanks for your help @fra-san, if you want go ahead and post your comment as an answer and I will accept it, the culprit was the quotation marks it looks like!

Comment: I don't really like answering after a problem has been solved in comments - it looks like just searching for reputation - but... actually comments will ultimately fade away, and an accepted answer will help others in better understanding the question.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, what you are trying to do is completely plausible.
The issue with your command is that the second pipe is happening on your local machine. Commands that are arguments to `ssh` should be quoted.

(Specific attention has to be paid to special characters like `$`: if expansion and/or command substitution have to happen remotely, those special characters has to be escaped or, alternatively, the remote command wrapped in *single* quotes. See, for reference, the `QUOTING` section in `man bash`).

What you probably need is something like

```
$ zcat myisoname.iso.gz | ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'dd of=/dev/sda'
```

Here, `dd` is just a possibility. You should be able to use a pipe to file too, as in

```
$ ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'cat - >/dev/sda'
```